# Alloy expression failed to be typechecked

Tags: logic, modeling, specifications, first-order-logic, alloy

I’m a beginner in Alloy (specification language) and need to do some further work based on a case study, which can be found [here](http://alloy.mit.edu/workshop/papers/chen.pdf) (code is on page 5). Relevant code:

```
open util/ordering[Time] as T0

pred Eavesdropping() {   
  some pro:Process | some m:Protected_Msg |  
  some t: (Time - T0/last) - T0/prev[T0/last] |   let t' = T0/t.next |
  let t'' = T0/t'.next |   !HasReadAccess[pro,m] && (m->t in pro.knows)
  &&   (m.contents->t not in pro.knows) &&   (m.contents->t'' in
  pro.knows) && IsUnique(m.contents) }
```

After correcting some syntax, I get this error message: “This expression failed to be typechecked”, and it highlights `t'` in `let t' = T0/t.next`. How do I typecheck `t'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error here is that next is a function in the module referred to by the alias `T0`, so the expression on the RHS of the let binding should be `t.T0/next` and not `T0/t.next`. But actually you don't need the `T0` anyway, since Alloy can determine which module is being referred to. So just remove all references to `T0` and it should compile fine.

Another comment: you can remove all those conjunction symbols and use implicit conjunction, writing

```
{ A B C }
```

instead of `A && B && C`.